# How to make each tab of the Nav bar fit across the screen equally

Tags: html, css

This is my first website and I'm creating a D&D character randomizer. I'm creating a Nav-bar and I'm trying to have each of the four bars fit across the screen equally (no matter screen size). I was hoping someone would be able to tell me what to add and take out of my existing code. I've included all the CSS and HTML needed to reproduce my issue.  Thanks again.

```css
/* CSS for the Menu */
#Menu {
    font-size: 25px; /* Font size of 25 px */
   }
   
   /* CSS for the Menu background */
   #Menu ul {
     list-style-type: none; /* No Bullets */
     overflow: hidden; /* No Scroll Wheel */
     background-color: rgb(77, 39, 21); /* Background colour of the Menu */
     margin-bottom: 0px; /* Margin from the top div is 0 */
     margin-top: 0px; /* Margin from the top div is 0 */
     padding: 0;
   }
   
   /* CSS for Menu Edges*/
   #Menu li {
     float: left; /* Menu is floated to the Left to make it all in one line */
     border-right: 1px solid rgb(104, 99, 99); /* Left border line of 1 px separating blocks. */
     border-left: 1px solid rgb(104, 99, 99); /* Right border line of 1 px separating blocks. */
   
   }
   
   /* CSS for Menu Tabs */
   #Menu li a {
     display: block; /* Turns it into a block display */
     color: rgb(187, 180, 180); /* Background colour of Text */
     text-align: center; /* Aligns text to the middle of the block */ 
     padding: 16px 177px; /* Padding of 16px and 177 px between blocks */
     text-decoration: none; /* Makes sure there are no underlines */
   }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "StylesheetQ.css">

<div id="Menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a class="active" href="Main Page.html">Home</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="About.html">About</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="Contacts.html">Contacts</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="Testimonials.html">Testimonials</li></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you need.

It uses Flexbox, which you can read more about here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

We just added `display: flex` to the `ul` element, and `flex: 1` to the `li`s.

`flex: 1` is a shorthand for `flex-grow: 1` and means: the remaining space in the
container will be distributed equally to all children.

`float` isn't needed anymore with flexbox, and so is the large horizontal padding of the `a` elements.

```css
/* CSS for the Menu */
#Menu {
    font-size: 25px; /* Font size of 25 px */
   }
   
   /* CSS for the Menu background */
   #Menu ul {
     list-style-type: none; /* No Bullets */
     overflow: hidden; /* No Scroll Wheel */
     background-color: rgb(77, 39, 21); /* Background colour of the Menu */
     margin-bottom: 0; /* Margin from the top div is 0 */
     margin-top: 0; /* Margin from the top div is 0 */
     padding: 0;
     display: flex; /* Add flexbox to list */
   }
   
   /* CSS for Menu Edges*/
   #Menu li {
     border-right: 1px solid rgb(104, 99, 99); /* Left border line of 1 px separating blocks. */
     border-left: 1px solid rgb(104, 99, 99); /* Right border line of 1 px separating blocks. */
     flex: 1  /* With flexbox we don't need float anymore */
   
   }
   
   /* CSS for Menu Tabs */
   #Menu li a {
     display: block; /* Turns it into a block display */
     color: rgb(187, 180, 180); /* Background colour of Text */
     text-align: center; /* Aligns text to the middle of the block */ 
     padding: 16px; /* Remove large horizontal padding */
     text-decoration: none; /* Makes sure there are no underlines */
   }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "StylesheetQ.css">

<div id="Menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a class="active" href="Main Page.html">Home</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="About.html">About</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="Contacts.html">Contacts</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="Testimonials.html">Testimonials</li></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the code below helps. I've commented on the places I made adjustments but I also provided you a cleaner version of your code so you can see what it could look like.

Also, consider maybe using CSS Grid as that may help reduce the code redundancy.

HTML/CSS Style

```css
*{
    margin:0;  
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
   }

#Menu {
    width:100%;
   }
   
#Menu ul {
    font-size: 100%; 
    list-style-type: none; 
   }
    
#Menu li {
     display: inline-block; 
     width: calc(100%/4); 
     text-align: center;
     padding: 16px 0px;
     float: left; 
     border-right: 1px solid rgb(104, 99, 99); 
     background-color: rgb(77, 39, 21); 
   }    
    
#Menu li:nth-child(1){ 
     border-left: 5px solid red; 
   }
   
#Menu a {
     color: rgb(187, 180, 180); 
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 100%;
   }

<!--end snippet-->

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "StylesheetQ.css">

<div id="Menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a class="active" href="Main Page.html">Home</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="About.html">About</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="Contacts.html">Contacts</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="Testimonials.html">Testimonials</li></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

HTML/CSS - With Comments

```css
*{
margin:0;   /* zero-out MARGINS and PADDING */
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box; /* helps keep dimensions of any block elements when they resize */
}

#Menu {
    /* don't target the Menu as a whole
    unless you want ALL the children to 
    have the same traits you intend for 
    your menu items (e.g. if you want menu
    items to be 25px as well as P elements
    throughout the contents of the div)*/
    
    width:100%; /* assuming you want it to expand the entire width of the window*/
    
 /* width:800px; <------ use this method if you want a FIXED size */
   }
   
   /* CSS for the Menu background */
   #Menu ul {
    font-size: 100%; /* Font size of 25 px */
    list-style-type: none; 
    }
   
   /* CSS for Menu Edges*/
   #Menu li {
     display: inline-block; /*INLINE-BLOCK (otherwise each list item takes up the whole line)*/
     width: calc(100%/4); /* 100% width DIVIDED by No. of Elements (list items) */
     text-align: center;
     float: left; /* Menu is floated to the Left to make it all in one line */
     border-right: 1px solid rgb(104, 99, 99); /* right border of ALL OTHER menu items. */
     background-color: rgb(77, 39, 21); 
     padding: 16px 0px; /* the padding is added to each INLINE-BLOCK element (each list item) rather than the anchor (link)*/
    }
    
#Menu li:nth-child(1){ /* left border of FIRST menu item. */
     border-left: 5px solid red; /*made it RED so you could see how it works. ALSO because of BOX-SIZING: border-box, the border grows INWARDS rather than make the element larger*/
    }
   
#Menu a {
     color: rgb(187, 180, 180); /* Background colour of Text */
     text-decoration: none; /* Makes sure there are no underlines */
     font-size: 100%;
   }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "StylesheetQ.css">

<div id="Menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a class="active" href="Main Page.html">Home</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="About.html">About</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="Contacts.html">Contacts</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="Testimonials.html">Testimonials</li></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: An issue I see with your approach is that the menu-item-links do not fill their box but are restricted to the text itself. Meaning you have to click exactly on the text; clicking somewhere else in the menu-item-box does nothing.

Comment: @Tad, you can also wrap the list items with the anchors <a href="#"><li>link you want to go to</li></a>